# Anytime I run the sudo pip3 install flask it show directory not owned by the current user

Tags: directory, delete, pip

Every time I run `sudo pip3 install flask`, I'm told the directory "is not owned by the current user":

```
/home/peter/.cache/pip/http is not owned by the current user
```

I have tried using sudo, but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `sudo` with `pip` if you are installing a package just for your user.

1. Fix you path ownership

   ```
   sudo chown -R peter:peter /home/peter/.cache/pip
   ```
2. Use pip without sudo

   ```
   pip3 install flask
   ```